# Topologically complete and $G_\delta$ theorem proof

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]
[image]

I don't understand the underlined part of the proof. It is very important, but it is not obvious.

[image]

Since ($S$, $e$) is complete, $y\in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function $g$ (which only serves the purpose of bounded the term to $1$, keeping continuity), we know that $g(t) \to 0$ iff $t \to 0$. IN particular $(g(t_n))_n$ is Cauchy iff $(t_n)_n$ is Cauchy.

Now, if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy for $e$, we know that for any *fixed* $n$ we trivially have (for all indices $k,l$):

$$2^{-n} g(|f_n(x_k) - f_n(x_l)|) \le e(x_k, x_l)$$ so that for large enough $k,l$ we have that $g(|f_n(x_k) - f_n(x_l)|) < \varepsilon$ for any prescribed $\varepsilon >0$, so that $(f_n(x_k))_k$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$ and thus converges (as $\Bbb R$ is complete).

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. Please also see my updated question description. I have another problem in the "only if" part of the same proof. Forget about my stupid question. That's because it is the known condition (S, e) is complete.